# How to run unit tests generated with Randoop in Spring-Boot 3.0 or higher?

Tags: java, spring-boot, randoop

I was able to generate unit tests using Randdop tool. I tried to import those junit in my spring-boot application but I could not figure out how to run them. I have a lot of errors due to unrecognized imports.

I tried to downgrade spring-boot-starter-junit lib to version 4 by following this guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing (section 3.1), witn no success.

this is the only dependency I included in my project other than proprietary Framework dependency which mainly contains dependencies such as lombook, common to all projects:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Although I include junit4, I have some other errors. One of this is about an inport which is missing on classpath: import spring.boot.loader....